What is all this —?

Solve on Penpa+
Across
2. Virtual people in game released current 4 down (3, abbr.)
10. Craving sex before church (4)
11. What Regis Philbin album came out 20 years ago, with the man and new vocalist Neil covering Milier's composition? (4,5,7)
13. What was the first US number one hit for Cyndi Lauper's trio – oddly, since putting a stop to an opportunity for self-care? (4,5,4)
14. Stripped ogre is extremely likely to be nightmarish (6)
15. Waits for sides of baked chocolate chips (6)
17. What team has had a bitter rivalry with the Chicago Blackhawks since the 1970s and surprisingly ousts bullies? (2,5,5)
21. What it means in ASL to have middle and ring finger pointing down, and the others straight out, puzzling Olive and solver? (1,4,3)
23. What Gulliver took when walking, for a Lilliputian army's members laying siege to army members with extremes of terrible power? (5,5)
24. Manchu-led China gets ready for ancient spiritual practice (6)
25. Myself and others each got sent back to set up new seats for the congregation (5)
27. What Superman seeks in his Fortress is very drunk bloke getting decapitated? (8)
30. What often precedes "folks" in cartoons featuring talking animals and ridiculously tall hats? (5,3)
32. Pixar production is a sci-fi film directed by Spielberg? That's an unexpected result! (5)
33. West wrote many biographies, including Lawrence of Arabia, for example (6)
34. What type of manufacturing process Toyota notably uses, as described by PM Trudeau in connection with US news magazine? (4-2-4)
37. What's an unlikely, very rare occurrence, with low, low chances, essentially? (4,4)
39. What religious rite many Christians go through in their teens, working with stern response, promoting original member of church? (12)
40. Things to practice on bass, or what a bass is covered in (6)
43. Confessed under interrogation, perhaps having partner gutlessly arrested, to get released (6)
45. What's a river crossing in the capital of the UK or Switzerland, further shortened but not entirely (7,6)
49. What's a way to order just a stiff drink and give number to heterosexual partner of Britrock's Dave, here shown naked? (8,2,6)
50. What's the style of many recordings of twelve answers here as rapper trades one unknown for another? (4)
51. Only 60% of capital in East Asia is used for visibility improvement efforts online (3, abbr.)
Down
1. For one, Washington D.C.'s northern limit is made explicit (6)
2. Fake slice of smoked meat? (4)
3. Like many joggers, we accelerated a little when entering enclosure (6)
4. Better half no longer included in better core document (4)
5. Group of comic book villains facing the Outsiders in water (7)
6. Peak amusement – comedian Carrey going bottomless (4)
7. Crime boss has ordered elite's elimination (8)
8. Traces of stuffy mist over Guangzhou? (4)
9. Diarist Nin penning play is oddly ignored in commentary (8)
12. Free time – one may get it upon arrival in Kona? Absolutely! (7)
16. Watch barbecue perhaps getting 50% smaller initially? (7)
18. New job with wise First Nations people (7)
19. Herb is visiting club, as I learned (5)
20. Capture sea creature feeding on river's bank (6)
21. Assistant comes up with hot kind of coffee (5)
22. One gets laid for one thousand dollars (3)
26. Prize selection gathered in fall (7)
27. Shut up and pay! (6)
28. It was recently brought to my attention, with injection of knowledge, that this type of hat may protect your brain? (7)
29. Nationalist chief supports political mass gathering in spirit (5)
31. Albert II accepted bishop's excuse (5)
33. It may be a drone competition (3)
34. Nothing is holding back ultimate payoffs (8)
35. Group that plays rock music for Satan – an abomination! (7)
36. Domestic sorts came flying, covered in bits of inkwork (4,4)
38. Painter Hieronymus eating real small amount of tomato soup (7)
41. Kitchen cutters and things perhaps cut when doing a hasty job, when one's heart is not in it (6)
42. Like a creep that's prone to acting sneakily when touring Eastern Arizona (6)
44. Foolish Greek leader goes against high-ranking Turk (4)
46. Hector perhaps has head struck when standing on heel of Achilles, a character in Greek mythology (4)
47. Too many classmates asked for seconds (4)
48. He was very publicly charged in party hall (4)

Completed grid:

 

Clue explanations:

 Across
 2. Virtual people in game released current 4 down (3, abbr.) | SMS | S(-i)MS
 10. Craving sex before church (4) | ITCH | IT + CH
 11. What Regis Philbin album came out 20 years ago, with the man and new vocalist Neil covering Milier's composition? (4,5,7) | WHEN YOU'RE SMILING | W/ + HE + N + YOUNG covering RESMILI*
 13. What was the first US number one hit for Cyndi Lauper's trio – oddly, since putting a stop to an opportunity for self-care? (4,5,4) | TIME AFTER TIME | T_I_ + AFTER inside ME TIME
 14. Stripped ogre is extremely likely to be nightmarish (6) | GRISLY | _GR_ IS L_Y
 15. Waits for sides of baked chocolate chips (6) | DELAYS | _D _E LAY'S
 17. What team has had a bitter rivalry with the Chicago Blackhawks since the 1970s and surprisingly ousts bullies? (2,5,5) | ST. LOUIS BLUES | OUSTSBULLIES*
 21. What it means in ASL to have middle and ring finger pointing down, and the others straight out, puzzling Olive and solver? (1,4,3) | I LOVE YOU | OLIVE* + YOU
 23. What Gulliver took when walking, for a Lilliputian army's members laying siege to army members with extremes of terrible power? (5,5) | GIANT STEPS | ANTS inside G.I.S with T_E P
 24. Manchu-led China gets ready for ancient spiritual practice (6) | QIGONG | QING getting GO
 25. Myself and others each got sent back to set up new seats for the congregation (5) | REPEW | WE PER<
 27. What Superman seeks in his Fortress is very drunk bloke getting decapitated? (8) | SOLITUDE | SO LIT (-d)UDE
 30. What often precedes "folks" in cartoons featuring talking animals and ridiculously tall hats? (5,3) | THAT'S ALL | TALLHATS*
 32. Pixar production is a sci-fi film directed by Spielberg? That's an unexpected result! (5) | UPSET | UP 'S ET
 33. West wrote many biographies, including Lawrence of Arabia, for example (6) | BYNAME | _E MANY B_<
 34. What type of manufacturing process Toyota notably uses, as described by PM Trudeau in connection with US news magazine? (4-2-4) | JUST-IN-TIME | JUSTIN + TIME
 37. What's an unlikely, very rare occurrence, with low, low chances, essentially? (4,4) | BLUE MOON | BLUE + MOO + _N_
 39. What religious rite many Christians go through in their teens, working with stern response, promoting original member of church? (12) | CONFIRMATION | ON + FIRM + ACTION, promoting C_ to beginning
 40. Things to practice on bass, or what a bass is covered in (6) | SCALES | ddef
 43. Confessed under interrogation, perhaps having partner gutlessly arrested, to get released (6) | SPRANG | SANG having P_R
 45. What's a river crossing in the capital of the UK or Switzerland, further shortened but not entirely (7,6) | CHELSEA BRIDGE | CH + ELSE + ABRIDGE(-d)
 49. What's a way to order just a stiff drink and give number to heterosexual partner of Britrock's Dave, here shown naked? (8,2,6) | STRAIGHT NO CHASER | giving NO. to STRAIGHT CHAS _ER_
 50. What's the style of many recordings of twelve answers here as rapper trades one unknown for another? (4) | JAZZ | JA(y->Z)-Z
 51. Only 60% of capital in East Asia is used for visibility improvement efforts online (3, abbr.) | SEO | SEO(-ul)

Down
 1. For one, Washington D.C.'s northern limit is made explicit (6) | STATED | STATE + D_
 2. Fake slice of smoked meat? (4) | SHAM | S_ + HAM
 3. Like many joggers, we accelerated a little when entering enclosure (6) | SWEATY | WE A_ entering STY
 4. Better half no longer included in better core document (4) | TEXT | EX included in _TT_
 5. Group of comic book villains facing the Outsiders in water (7) | HYDRATE | HYDRA + T_E
 6. Peak amusement – comedian Carrey going bottomless (4) | FUJI | FU(-n) JI(-m)
 7. Crime boss has ordered elite's elimination (8) | DELETION | DON has ELITE*
 8. Traces of stuffy mist over Guangzhou? (4) | SMOG | S_ M_ O_ G_ &lit!
 9. Diarist Nin penning play is oddly ignored in commentary (8) | ANALYSIS | ANAIS penning _L_Y_S
 12. Free time – one may get it upon arrival in Kona? Absolutely! (7) | LEISURE | LEI + SURE
 16. Watch barbecue perhaps getting 50% smaller initially? (7) | LOOKOUT | (c->L)OOKOUT
 18. New job with wise First Nations people (7) | OJIBWES | JOBWISE*
 19. Herb is visiting club, as I learned (5) | BASIL | _B AS I _L
 20. Capture sea creature feeding on river's bank (6) | CORRAL | CORAL surrounding _R
 21. Assistant comes up with hot kind of coffee (5) | IRISH | SIRI< + H
 22. One gets laid for one thousand dollars (3) | EGG | E.G. + G
 26. Prize selection gathered in fall (7) | PLUMMET | PLUM + MET
 27. Shut up and pay! (6) | SETTLE | ddef
 28. It was recently brought to my attention, with injection of knowledge, that this type of hat may protect your brain? (7) | TINFOIL | TIL surrounding INFO
 29. Nationalist chief supports political mass gathering in spirit (5) | DEMON | N_ supporting DEMO
 31. Albert II accepted bishop's excuse (5) | ALIBI | AL II surroudning B
 33. It may be a drone | competition (3) | BEE | ddef
 34. Nothing is holding back ultimate payoffs (8) | JACKPOTS | JACK + STOP<
 35. Group that plays rock music for Satan – an abomination! (7) | SANTANA | SATANAN*
 36. Domestic sorts came flying, covered in bits of inkwork (4,4) | TAME CATS | CAME* covered in TATS
 38. Painter Hieronymus eating real small amount of tomato soup (7) | BORSCHT | BOSCH eating R + T_
 41. Kitchen cutters and things perhaps cut when doing a hasty job, when one's heart is not in it (6) | CORERS | COR(-_n_)ERS
 42. Like a creep that's prone to acting sneakily when touring Eastern Arizona (6) | SLEAZY | SLY touring E AZ
 44. Foolish Greek leader goes against high-ranking Turk (4) | GAGA | G + AGA
 46. Hector perhaps has head struck when standing on heel of Achilles, a character in Greek mythology (4) | EROS | (-h)ERO + _S
 47. Too many classmates asked for seconds (4) | ALSO | _A _L _S _O
 48. He was very publicly charged in party hall (4) | DOJO | O.J. in DO

What's going on with the theme?

 As hinted in 50 across, there are twelve other answers in the grid that are also the names of jazz recordings - in fact, every clue that begins with the word "What" has such an answer!


Aargh, ninjaed by less than a minute. Well done!

@GarethMcCaughan even with a crossword this big, I figured it was gonna be close haha

Close for me too - on my final 4 clues... Well done - always happy to be beaten by a complete write-up with links and all :)

Two left...sad! But happy for a Jafe puzzle :-)
